# How can rename be atomic when disk sector writes are not?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure

I was reading [OS: Three Easy Pieces - files and Directories](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/file-intro.pdf), page 14. It is mentioned that rename call is implemented as an atomic call with respect to system crashes. Lets say, I'm renaming file *a.txt* in directory *dir* to *b.txt*. Lets say, power failure occurs while writing the sector containing inode or data blocks of *dir*. Won't this leave this sector half-written and in an inconsistent state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> power failure occurs while writing the sector containing inode or data blocks of dir. Won't this leave this sector half-written and in an inconsistent state?

Assuming a spinning harddisk:

First, when a power failure occurs, the harddisk doesn't go away immediately: It has still enough power stored somewhere to move the read-write hand to a landing zone to avoid head crashes. (Real early harddisks didn't have this feature, so you actually *could* get head crashes with those, if you didn't issue a "park" command). So I would assume it also has enough power to finish writing a particular sector. (Though I don't know for sure, I never looked at a harddrive in a lab setting, and measured what happens through a power failure).

Second, harddisk writes use an encoding that "distributes" one original bit over many bits with error correction. At current densities *some* physical bits will always get read wrong, so this is a necessity. So if a half-finished write could actually occur, the sector would become unreadable (and not inconsistent).

So if you want, there's a third state between "rename successful" and "rename didn't happen", namely "directory no longer readable", but this third state can also occur for other reasons, not related to any renaming.

Assuming a SSD:

SSDs don't rewrite blocks, the write a new block and then atomically update their mapping to say "this logical block has now been replaced by this physical block". The atomic update is a single write operation, and again there will be enough power left in capacities etc. that this can succeed even when a power failure occurs.

And again, there's a third state for an SSD, namely "too many write operations have occured and the SSD can be no longer written", but in that case the directory will still have the old name.

Answer (score 2):

The question is: What is meant by the word "atomic", as what you
(and most people) will understand is different than what was meant
by the author of this phrase.

So let's dispel this myth:
"it is atomic so inconsistencies cannot happen".
Wrong!

When moving a file inside the same filesystem (rename),
the system call is indeed atomic, but what is meant is that this
is atomic with respect to the software environment.

Atomicity means here that any process that looks for the file will
either see it at its old location or at its new location.
No process will be able to observe that the file has a different
link count, or that the file is present with the old name/directory
after being present in the new name/directory, or that the file is
missing under both new and old names.

However, if the system crashes due to a bug, a disk error or a
power loss, there is no guarantee that the filesystem is left in
a consistent state, let alone that the move isn't left half-done.

Neither Windows nor Linux offer in general a guarantee of
atomicity with respect to hardware events.
Which is why these operating systems include disk test and repair
utilities, `chkdsk` for Windows and `fsck` in Linux, and many other
utilities both free and commercial.

Some file-system formats offer better resiliency to crashes for the
rename operation. The Linux `ext` family may excel here.
More resilient disk file-formats include a journal of operations that
allows to complete or undo interrupted disk operations,
with automatic recovery during the boot.